# forwarding streaming packets using ion-dtn

Tags: networking, gstreamer, dtn

OS : Ubuntu 14.04
ion : 3.2.2
In my current setup, I am using gstreamer utility  to stream live video.
 The system has Ip address of 192.168.58.10( say for example). I am streaming it to another machine say 192.168.58.12 port 5000.
From 2nd machine I want to use Ion-dtn to stream it to different endpoints. I am completely clueless how to proceed.

I have done bit of research and found that bssStreamingApp utility and bsspadmin can do it but I failed to find any examples. Can some one please advice me. Earlier I have integrated bpsource in my application to send messages or text stream and it was quite successful.

Thanks in advance for help or any criticism

Comment: really dont know what’s wrong in this question  that people tried to close it.

Comment: maybe because you question is too broad.. usualy people dont like questions of type "give me solution".. you should give more details on what you tried and what exactly failed/didnt work.. I will just guess (I dont know your requirements) you may want to use gstreamer [rtsp server](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-rtsp-server.html) to stream to different endpoints from second server.. why do you need dtn?

Comment: @otopolsky, Thanks mate for reply. Well its one of the requirement for the project to use dtn to forward it to another endpoints .   Well just to explain my points , " i am not looking for give me solution"  . All I need is bit of hint on how to use bssdriver or bssStreamingApp. I really dont know how to use these commands and tehre is no sample example or snippet of code aviliabel on net.